# How to avoid creation of a float page with figure*

Tags: floats, placeins

I want to prevent a `figure*` going to next page, and be displayed atop the section. Below you find the code, and I also provide an [overleaf view-only link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ykdszffsdbjy).

This [past question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366315/prevent-float-page-in-twocolumn-document-after-clearpage) is also related, but using `\twocolumn[{%` as suggested breaks usage later on (it forces a page break, so you need to go back to figure* a-posteriori).

I have also tried to fiddle with \FloatBarrier to no avail.

Any suggestions?
Much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[review]{cvpr}      % To produce the REVIEW version
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\loremshort}[1]{{\lipsum[1][0-#1]}}

% FROM: https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html
% OUTCOME: does not work...
% \input{attempt1.tex}

\def\cvprPaperID{*****} % *** Enter the CVPR Paper ID here
\def\confName{CVPR}
\def\confYear{2023}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[tb!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Why does this figure not want to stay on page 1?}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
\section{Section}
\loremshort{10}
\end{document}
```

Yet, the output I get is the following:
[image: compiled resut]

And this is even if I add `attempt1.tex`, according to the [tricks discussed here](https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html):

```
% Alter some LaTeX defaults for better treatment of figures:
% See p.105 of "TeX Unbound" for suggested values.
% See pp. 199-200 of Lamport's "LaTeX" book for details.
%   General parameters, for ALL pages:
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}    % max fraction of floats at top
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8} % max fraction of floats at bottom
%   Parameters for TEXT pages (not float pages):
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}     % 2 may work better
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}    % for 2-column pages
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{0.9} % fit big float above 2-col. text
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs
%   Parameters for FLOAT pages (not text pages):
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}  % require fuller float pages
% N.B.: floatpagefraction MUST be less than topfraction !!
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{0.7}   % require fuller float pages
```

### Trick from David

The twocolumn trick is not quite satisfying:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\loremshort}[1]{{\lipsum[1][0-#1]}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\lorem}[1]{{\blindtext[#1]}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lorem{2}
\twocolumn[{
% \begin{figure*}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\captionof{figure}{Why does this figure not want to stay on page 1?}
\end{center}
% \end{figure*}
}]
\section{Method}
\loremshort{10}
\end{document}
```

Because it generates a **hard page break** whenever it's used (similar to clearpage).

[image]

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`cvpr.sty' not found.` is that needed for this example?

Comment: it's in the overleaf; not sure I guess any 2col template would do the same?

Comment: even your edited example has less than a page of text so a two-column float will necessarily hit the end of document. This is not an issue in a document with more than one page The trick I show is a way to get the figure on the first page so forced page break is not a problem

Comment: Yes, your solution works for page1, but elsewhere, it has the same issues as placein's FloatBarrier (it creates a \clearpage effect wherever it's inserted).

But for a "teaser" (twocol float on page1 it works).
However, that's not what I seek.

Comment: if you have more than one page the problem you show here does not arise so my suggestion is not needed

Comment: Assuming you have more than one page, the input for a `figure*` must be read by LaTeX *before* anything else is read for the page where you intend the figure to be placed.  But, as David implied, most document classes prohibit a figure being placed at the top of the first page, so the earliest a `figure*` can be placed is on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

Two-column floats come, at the earliest, on the next page, as there is no next page here the float can not be positioned at all until it is flushed out by the implicit `\clearpage` at `\end{document}`. `\clearpage` necessarily treats all floats as allowed on float pages as it has to ensure they are all output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

%\usepackage[review]{cvpr}      % To produce the REVIEW version
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\loremshort}[1]{{\lipsum[1][0-#1]}}

% FROM: https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html
% OUTCOME: does not work...
% \input{attempt1.tex}

\def\cvprPaperID{*****} % *** Enter the CVPR Paper ID here
\def\confName{CVPR}
\def\confYear{2023}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\captionof{figure}{Why does this figure not want to stay on page 1?}
\end{center}
}]
\section{Section}
\loremshort{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned earlier, I know this works "just" for this example. The issue is that \clearpage is often used when doing simultaneous edits on overleaf (somebody works on intro, somebody works on method, and we don't change the layout of each other's doc).

Issue is that the twocolumn trick forces a hard break in the text (similar to \clearpage) even when that's not desierable.

Comments don't allow images, let me post this as an answer to show you.

Comment: I followed the guidelines and added more to my original post.